# NSURLRequest does not return a response

Tags: objective-c

I have simple test app running on the simulator with Xcode 7.1 / Objective C. See the code below.  No matter what I do or what URL I use, the Response is `nil` and the data is `nil`. What am I doing wrong? I can access these URLs from my Mac with now issues. Thanks in advance

```
NSString *urlAsStringTEST = @"http://www.yahoo.com";
NSURL *urlTEST = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsStringTEST];
NSURLRequest *urlRequestTEST = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlTEST];

NSURLResponse *responseTEST = nil;
NSError *errorTEST = nil;

NSLog(@"Firing synchronous url connection...");

NSData *dataTEST = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequestTEST
                                         returningResponse:&responseTEST
                                                     error:&errorTEST];
if ([dataTEST length] > 0 && errorTEST == nil) {
}
```

Comment: use `https` not `http` and test it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS 9 and OS X 10.11 added a technology called App Transport Security, which may be causing you some problems.  By default it will block all non-HTTPS requests or HTTPS requests with outdated security mechanisms the app tries to make.

In order to make other types of requests (HTTP, or HTTPS without the most current security mechanisms), you must setup exceptions for App Transport Security in your Info.plist.  You can read more about how to do this in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33).

You can setup specific exceptions for specific domains by adding something like the following to your Info.plist.  Which exception you enable depends on the problem with the domain, and will vary (see the documentation linked above for the various options):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>youtube.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

A less-desirable shotgun approach to allowing all requests, which is perhaps useful for debugging or apps that need to load arbitrary content is as follows (you would add this to your Info.plist):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: I tried adding the 'less desirable shotgun approach' but still returns nil. Looks like it's making the request.  Any ideas.. thx

Comment: @Jon When I paste your code into a project, and add that plist entry, I see content in the response.  You may need to perform a clean and re-build to make sure Xcode picks up your Info.plist changes.

Comment: @Jon You might try creating a new project and pasting the code above into the app delegate (assuming iOS), adding the Plist entry and trying there.  Perhaps there's something else wrong with your project.  You may also try the age old restart Xcode/Simulator/Computer technique.

Comment: Worked with new project